# Remove comma delimitter along xaxis D3

Tags: d3.js

How do I remove the comma delmitter between thousands along the xaxis? I've tried using the `.format("")`, but that doesn't work.

```
var xAxis = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1000, 2000])
  .range([ 0, width ]);
  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "myXaxis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xAxis).tickSize(-height*).ticks(100).tickPadding(50)).format('')
    .select(".domain").remove()
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xAxis))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1000, 2000])
  .range([ 0, width ]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat(d3.format(""));

svg.append("g")
  .call(xAxis)
```